# LINQPad Requesting Custom Assembly

Tags: sql-server-ce, linqpad

I read an article about using [linqpad to open a SQL CE 4.0 database](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/10/18/using-linqpad-to-open-sql-ce-4-0-databases.aspx), which shows a "LINQPad Connection" screenshot where the "data context" is chosen automatically.  But when I downloaded LINQPad, the "data context" portion of that same dialogue was replaced with a "Path to Custom Assembly," with no default.  Anyone know what I should be searching for (it has a 'browse' option) to enable my connection?  Why did this interface change occur?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select the the first option on the top half of the screen ie Default (Linq To Sql) then you don't need to specify the custom assembly.

If you read the comments in the article, Joe Albahari (who wrote LinqPad) mentioned this change.

Answer (score 1):

Just click the SQL CE 4.0 provider button in the middle of this dialog, and point to the sdf file.

Comment: That is what I had done, but the dialogue will not allow me to go one step further (no connection testing or otherwise) until I supply the custom assembly.  I think you are using a different version of LINQPad than I.  I think you are using the version available at the time the article I referenced was written.